# Exporting list to CSV in one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, export-to-csv

I want to export a list to csv in a single column with each entry starting a new line.

My list is like:

```
['Jimmy French', 'Casey Fryer', 'Jane Pickens', 'Tommy L. Garcetti', 'Nada Lewis']
```

Following another stack overflow question, my code reads:

```
with open("export_5.csv","w") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, lineterminator=',')
    w.writerow(phone_names_value_list)
```

The output is:

```
Jimmy French,Casey Fryer,Jane Pickens,Tommy L. Garcetti,Nada Lewis,
```

Is this because I am viewing it in notepad? Is there something I should change to make it print in one column?

**Also, how might I remove the comma?

Comment: View the csv file in excel

Comment: it's because your list is 1D list and when you use `w.writerow(list)` it assumes that the list should be a row and writes it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write it like this:

```
with open("export_5.csv","w") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    for item in phone_names_value_list:
        w.writerow([item])
```

or with pandas you can do it like:

```
import pandas as pd
a=['Jimmy French', 'Casey Fryer', 'Jane Pickens', 'Tommy L. Garcetti', 'Nada Lewis']
df=pd.DataFrame(a)
df.to_csv('output_file.csv', index=False,header=None)
```

Comment: The output there was:

```
ⱔⱡⱴⱹⱡⱮⱡⰠⱈⰮⰠⱆⱲⱥⱮⱣⱨⱃⱡⱳⱥⱹⰠⱍⱣⱧⱯⱷⱡⱮⱊⱡⱮⱥⰠⱊⱯⱹⱮⱥⱲⱄⱥⱶⱩⱮⰠⱌⰮⰠⱂⱯⱯⱮⱥⱎⱡⱩⱤⱡⰠⱇⱵⱴⱨⱲⱩⱥ
```

Comment: The first iteration. Cant use pandas here.Also added, encoding='utf-8'

Comment: Op! Just checked on a computer with excel. It is working fine.

Comment: it's only because you have used `lineterminator=','` comma as line terminator that is why you can't see it properly in notepad. I have edited it to  `lineterminator='\n'` now you can see it properly in notepad as well

Answer (score 0):

A single column csv is a plain text file with one field per line. Just print that.

Possible code:

```
with open("export_5.csv","w") as f:
    for field in phone_names_value_list:
        print(field, file=f)
```

The only problem in above code, it that nothing guarantees that the lines will be ended with `\r\n` as proper csv files should be. If it matters, you will have to explicitely write them in binary mode:

```
with open("export_5.csv","bw") as f:
    for field in phone_names_value_list:
        print(field.encode() + b'\r\n', file=f)
```

Comment: Don’t forget to escape commas